# ExtJS 4 and grid size

Tags: javascript, grid, extjs4

I want to construct simple register with the grid component with tittle bar and bottom bar constant (I mean title visible always on top and bottom bar visible always on the bottom of the screen):

```
-------------------------------------
|            title bar              |
|-----------------------------------|
|                                   |
|  pure grid, only rows             |
|                                   |
|-----------------------------------|
|            bottom bar             |
-------------------------------------
```

simple but I have a problem to set grid parameters. When I set "layout: 'fit'" bottom bar is not visible until I scroll down to the end of the screen. And in this place I can't see title bar.
I want to scroll only rows but app scrolls all the elements.

Be so kind as to prompt me how should I set parameters.

Something like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Ranking', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    ...

    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.View',
        'Ext.grid.column.Number'
    ],


    resizable: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this, 
            upper_tag = {
                xtype:  'toolbar',
                height: 60,
                items: [
                    { xtype: 'label', ... }
                    '->',
                    { xtype: 'label', ... }
                ]
            },
            lower_tag = {
                 xtype:  'toolbar',
                 height: 60,
                 items: [
                     {  xtype: 'label', ... }
                     {  xtype:  'button', ... }
                     '->',
                     {  xtype:  'button', ... }
                     {  xtype:  'button', ... }
                 ]
             };

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                upper_tag,
                {
                    xtype:  'gridpanel',
                    itemId: 'GRD_PW',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    height: 750,
                    store:  'PW_Store',
                    columns: { ... }
                    viewConfig: {  ... }
                },
                lower_tag
            ]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

To be clear, this is the better explanation of my need:

```
    1 row
    2 row
    3 row
    4 row
 -------------------------------------
 |            title bar              |
 |-----------------------------------|
 |  5 row                           ^|
 |  6 row                           ||
 |  7 row   pure grid, only rows    || <-- this is browser screen
 |  8 row                           ||
 |  9 row                           ||
 | 10 row                           v|
 |-----------------------------------|
 |            bottom bar             |
 -------------------------------------
   11 row 
   12 row 
   13 row 
    ...
```

So that's no way to restrict number of rows on the screen and set pagination. It should use full hight of the browser screen. Sometimes 5 sometimee 20 rows.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: `upper_tag` and `lower_tag` should be `dockedItems`.

Comment: I tried to but when I delete "height: 750" in GRD_PW and when I have to diplay 100 rows lower toolbar is under the last row (I mean I must scroll down to see it). That's my problem

Comment: Post a test case then. https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: add pagination and restrict the number to the height of your screen eg. 20 records in the grid